# How can I align parenthesis block?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

With following codes,

```java
bytes[i] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(j), 16) << 4)
        | Character.digit(hex.charAt(++j), 16));
```

How can I align contents between `(` and `)`? So I can see following?

```java
bytes[i] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(j), 16) << 4)
                   | Character.digit(hex.charAt(++j), 16));
```

Which one should I check in `Preferences / Editor / CodeStyle / Java / Wrapping and Braces`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `Binary expressions / Align when multiline`

Enabled:
[image: Code style with option enabled]

Disabled (default): 
[image: Code style with option disabled]

To quickly find the corresponding code style option, select the code snippet in Editor and invoke Alt+Enter intention action then select **Adjust code style settings** from the popup:
[image]

then locate the option:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful addition @Andrey, I wasn't aware of that option :-)